# Why interp2 and interpn give different results in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I find interp2 and interpn give different results in MATLAB despite that I use the same method. Please try these two samples.

`test1=interp2([1,2],[6,7],[0,14317;25217,45817],1.1107,6.1348,'linear');`

`test2=interpn([1,2],[6,7],[0,14317;25217,45817],1.1107,6.1348,'linear');`

The first one yields 5078 and the second one yields 4815 (same as hand-calculated)

By looking into the functions, I find interp2 uses makegriddedinterp while interpn uses griddedInterpolant. Could someone tell the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It takes me a while to realize:
interp2 is for the meshgrid format while interpn is for the ngrid format.
Therefore, the x and y should switch in interp2! (It is the same in interp1)
test3 is equal to test2.
`test3=interp2([6,7],[1,2],[0,14317;25217,45817],6.1348,1.1107,'linear');`